# Blocker with First Strike and Blocker with Double Strike

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I'm playing Magic Duels: Origins and I blocked a 2/2 with a 1/1 double strike and a 1/1 first strike. My interpretation is that that equals 2 damage during the first strike phase and 1 damage during the combat phase from my creatures, and 2 damage during the combat phase from his. However, this resulted in all three creatures being destroyed. Is there an interaction between first strike and double strike I'm unaware of, or is the game coded wrong?

Comment: It depends on which blocked first (or how the attacker chose to distribute the damage) He could have chosen to deal damage to the Double striker first then the first striker this would cause all three to die as the double striker did not get the chance to strike the second time.

Comment: Why? I thought it would be that all first strike damage (one from first strike and one from double strike) would be dealt to the 2/2 before its 2 damage was dealt to any of my creatures

Comment: @NathanTaylor That's not correct. Creatures without first or double strike do not get to assign damage in the first damage step. There is no possible way that an attacking 2/2 could deal any damage at all to a blocking 1/1 with double strike and a blocking 1/1 with first strike (unless something else was also affecting the board that the OP neglected to mention).

Comment: @Rainbolt hmm I didn't think double strike meant it dealt damage first the way it sounds is that the first striker attacks first deals 1 damage then dies and  on the first strike of the double strikers attack the blocker deals his damage with it before the second attack happened then it would seem all would die. Does double strike apply to a blocking phase too I thought it was just attacking?

Comment: @RobertWertz The only other thing that maybe could of have effected it is if it had a regenerate ability did you see him tap a land at all? or did it have Deathtouch? or protection of some kind (Maybe from colour or creature type?)

Comment: @NathanTaylor Double strike means the creature deals damage equal to its power in both the first strike and normal strike phases. This occurs on both attacking and blocking. And while the creature could regenerate, he didn't have the mana to do so, and if he had then the creature would have been removed from combat per the rules and not been around to deal damage in the main phase. No deathtouch or protection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like it is a bug. Since the way the Combat Damage Step works is

1. Each player decides how their creatures will deal damage
2. If any creatures have First Strike or Double Strike they deal their damage
3. State Based Actions are checked, anything that triggers off of damage happens, players get priority
4. Any creatures with Double Strike or that didn't deal damage in the first Combat Damage Step deal their damage

So what should have happened is what you were expecting, your creatures deal 1 damage each in the first Combat Damage Step, then when SBAs are checked it should have died due to having damage marked on it equal to its toughness.